Take Vs Have. Why do people say 'take'?
I cannot see any reason for saying;
'take' a look
Take a seat
take a shower - take a bath
take a walk
take a nap
take the train/ bus/ other.
How do they make sense? You cannot 'take' any of these.
Actually, you can take a seat (a physical thing) to another part of the room/ building... or home with you, ha ha.
I have a look, have a seat or sit, have a shower (or I simply shower), have or go for a bath and I go for a walk or run. I use or ride a train, bus/ other.
How is 'take' even considered?

Those are mostly idioms just like must exist in your language. Most languages have more than one way to say the same thing. That said, take has 20 main meanings and numerous submeanings in Merriam Webster. And if you have the patience, you can suss them out to fit your phrases.

Note that at least some of them depend on the variety. In British English it is more common to have a bath, a shower, a rest, than to take them.

When I was young, I was given a humorous French phrase book in which Je voudrais prendre un bain was translated as I would like to take a bath and illustrated with someone carrying a bathtub away! We do sometimes 'take baths' in the UK, also we more often 'take the train' or 'go by train' than 'ride' it.

My uncle was a portrait photographer, and he drilled into me that one doesn’t take pictures, but make them. Years later I learned of cultures that strongly object to appearing in photographs, believing that producing such images literally robs the subjects of their souls.

@KateBunting - canonical old misogynist 'joke': Comedian: women are strange! Take my wife! Someone, please take my wife!

The question "why use this word" is never really answerable.  The meaning of the word "take" includes its use in idioms like "take a shower".  What you are asking is "Why does English use the same word "take" in "take a shower" and "take a bag (to another room)"  but in my language we use different words!"  You are asking "Why can't English just be the same as my language with different words?"  -  If your language happened to use the same idiom, you wouldn't think to ask the question.

There is no "President of English" who "considers" what words should be used.  So the question "was this considered" is unanswerable

Words often have multiple definitions. Especially when you're talking about subtle distinctions. So yes, "take" can mean "to pick up and carry away", like "Take a book" could mean to select a book from the collection and leave with it. But "take" can also mean to do or use something. "Take a shower" means to go through the process of showering. "Take a seat" means to sit on it. Etc.
Trying to use definition #1 of a word when in context it is clear that definition #2 is meant doesn't prove that the language is irrational. Just that some words have more than one definition. Sometimes this can be a basis for a joke. Like you could say "I took a seat" and say it in a context that would lead listeners to think you meant that you sat down, and then shift the context so it's clear that you meant you stole a chair. Worded properly that could make a funny joke. But it would be a joke, caused by deliberately constructing a misleading sentence to create an ambiguity.

In these phrases, take is a light verb.  This means that the real meaning comes from the other verb in the phrase.  Other light verbs in English include have, make, give, and do.
This is just part of how English works; don't worry about the literal meaning of take/have/make/give/do.

The OP asks: "How is 'take' even considered?"
take is one of the most productive verbs in the English language, entering the language from the language of Scandinavian settlers on the island.

Given the heading, it's worth noting that take and have are exactly the same in this respect. Have can be literal: to own or possess. But it can also have other meanings:

Have a seat. (meaning that I can sit on it, not that I can take ownership of it.)
Have a good time. (meaning that I want you to enjoy yourself, not that you will own the time period.)

There's a great cartoon that draws on this range of meaning. The context is a job interview for IKEA, the company that sells flat pack furniture for home assembly. The applicant walks into the room, only to find a set of chair parts lying on the floor. The interviewer says, Take a seat! There's also a version of the same cartoon with the words Have a seat! You can see the two versions in these links:

have a seat
take a seat

